# Accessing favorite/hearted images when choosing an image with Samsung's Gallery app

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, gallery

In the Samsung Galaxy Note 9's Gallery app, there isn't a separate Favorite Photos folder. Instead, a button on top of the albums page labeled Favorites opens up hearted photos.

The problem with this is my favorite/hearted photos don't appear as a separate folder in WhatsApp when I try to attach a photo. For example, I press the attach button, Gallery, and there is no separate folder for my hearted/favorite photos.

How to quickly access those photos?

Comment: @Robert Edited the question. Please try now.

Comment: I've done further edit based on my understanding of the question. If there's something wrong or missing, feel free to [edit] and fix it/add more detail. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reach you installed gallery from within WhatsApp by either longpressing the "gallery"-button within the attachement-menu or by clicking it, then clicking the three dots in the upper right corner.

---

Old Answer with the assumption, that you were asking for WhatsApp-Favorites:

The starred messages are no seperate folder in the gallery, but a list within WhatsApp.
To get to this list follow these steps:
1. Open WhatsApp.
2. Tap More options. (The three dots)
3. Tap "Starred messages".

Comment: I just changed the question text. Please try now.